# how to keep collapsed div as open after postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

Below is my Javascript to expand/collapse gridview rows in asp.net

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function divexpandcollapse(divname) {
        var div = document.getElementById(divname);
        var img = document.getElementById('img' + divname);
        if (div.style.display == "none") {
            div.style.display = "inline";
            img.src = "Img1/minus.gif";
        } else {
            div.style.display = "none";
            img.src = "Img1/plus.gif";
        }
    }
</script>
```

And this is my gridview templatefield

```
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <a href="JavaScript:divexpandcollapse('div<%# Eval("ClaimMasterId") %>');">
                    <img id='imgdiv<%# Eval("ClaimMasterId") %>' width="9px" border="0" src="Img1/plus.gif" alt="" title="Add Action Notes" /></a>                        
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle Width="10px" VerticalAlign="Middle"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:TemplateField>


        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                   <td colspan="100%" style="background:#F5F5F5">
                       <div id='div<%# Eval("ClaimMasterId") %>'  style="overflow:auto; display:none; position: relative; left: 15px; overflow: auto;">
                           <div style="width:900px; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175); box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175); -moz-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);">
                       <table>
                           <tr>
                               <td style="vertical-align:top">
                                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="MoveToRBL" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="MoveToRBL_SelectedIndexChanged" >
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Review" Value="Review" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Call" Value="Call"></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Re-Call" Value="ReCall"></asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Audit" Value="Audit"></asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:RadioButtonList>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                               </td>
                               <td style="vertical-align:top">
                                   <asp:ImageButton ID="SaveButton" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Img1/save32.png" ToolTip="Save" OnClick="SaveButton_Click" />
                               </td>
                           </tr>
                       </table>
                               </div>
                       </div>                     
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle Width="1px" ></ItemStyle>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Expanding & Collapsing are working fine but whenever RadioButttonList "MoveToRBL" is clicked, then the expanded div collapsed. Then I need to click the plus symbol again to expand it. Why its happened, how to stop it. Anything I need to change in Javascript, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieved thru UpdatePanel with Conditional mode as below.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList ID="AllocateToDDL" runat="server" CssClass="dropdown" Visible="true" Width="135px" AppendDataBoundItems="True" DataSourceID="GetARmembers" DataTextField="EmpName" DataValueField="EmpName" >
<asp:ListItem Text="Select the Caller" Value="NA" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="MoveToRBL" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```